# Change android button based on database values

Tags: android

i am currently trying to learn how to develop android application. I have a simple android application. I have set up a database table using wampserver. The table "tv" has two columns "samsung" and "status". I have an xml file which has a button "tvStatus". How can I change the the button color into red if the value "status" from database is off. and change the button color to blue if the "status" is on?

Answer (score 1):

You can set a selector to your button.
Create a new xml file on drawable folder.
For example: button_selector.xml
And put this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item android:state_enabled="false" android:drawable="@android:color/holo_red_dark"/>
        <item android:drawable="@android:color/holo_green_dark"/>
</selector>
```

In your activity layout, set android:background="@drawable/button_selector"

When your the status is 'On':
button.setEnabled(true);
Otherwise:
button.setEnabled(false);

It should work.